# Stop Youtube Video When Close Modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've got a modal that opens a Youtube video. The modal is set to open whenever you reset the session.

I'm trying to make it so that when you close the modal (either by hitting the "x" or by clicking anywhere outside the modal) the youtube video stops playing, but I'm at a loss.

Here's my code so far:

```js
//resetting/refreshing the session:
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
if (sessionStorage.getItem("story") !== 'true') {
  sessionStorage.setItem("story", "true");
  $("#myModal").modal();
  }

$('#reset-session').on('click',function(){
sessionStorage.setItem('story','');
});
});

//my attempt at stopping the video:

function toggleVideo(state) {
    // if state == 'hide', hide. Else: show video
    var div = document.getElementById("myModal");
    var iframe = div.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
    div.style.display = state == 'hide' ? 'none' : '';
    func = state == 'hide' ? 'pauseVideo' : 'playVideo';
    iframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + func + '","args":""}','*');
}
```

```css
 body {
    background-color: #335C64; 
    margin:10px;
 }
 

    h4 {
      color: #FFD5C2;
  }

  .desc {
    color: #FFD5C2;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    }
  .btn-sm {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
```

```html
   
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<h4>Bootstrap Modal with SessionStorage</h4>
<hr />
<p class="desc">
  Click this button to <strong>Refresh</strong> the page.
</p>
<a href="" id="refresh-page" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
  Refresh Page
</a>

<p class="desc">
  Click this button to <strong>Reset</strong> and <strong>Refresh</strong> the page. 
</p>
<a href="" id="reset-session" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">
  Reset Session
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title text-primary">Victor Frankenstein</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VZzZKuQUguk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal"> Close </button>
</div>
</div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/jackcode1/pen/ZEpbRQq

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy, perhaps too easy, solution:

```
$("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("#myModal iframe").attr("src", $("#myModal iframe").attr("src"));
});
```

That's it. I guess I was over complicating this.

Comment: Thanks for following up with the answer! I was trying everything and this finally got it working.